# Multiple Regression - ANOVA and Coefficients Tables

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

After conducting a multiple regression, I obtained p-value<0.05 (significant) in the ANOVA table; in the coefficients table, 2 out of the 4 explanatory variables are not significant. How do I interpret this analysis?
Thanks

Comment: For those two, you don't know with confidence whether the population coefficients are negative, 0, or positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is actually very common.  The ANOVA confirms that your model estimates provide a much better fit than just using a naïve model that would take the average as a best estimate.  And, it does this at a statistically significant level.

You have 4 variables.  And, 2 of them are associated with statistically significant regression coefficients.  That's good.

You also have 2 variables that are associated with regression coefficients that are not statistically significant.  And, that is not necessarily bad given certain conditions.  Make sure that those variables are associated with coefficient signs that are directionally correct and convergent with the assumed direction of their explanatory influence on the dependent variable.  Next, look at the P values.  Are the P values not that high anyway.  Different audiences and circumstances will be associated with different tolerance of P values.  In certain circumstances, model developers want their P values to be at least less than 0.20.  Some others would prefer <0.15 or even <0.10.  And, some others will have no tolerance whatsoever for variables not statistically significant at the 0.05 level.

I am somewhat agnostic on the above.  But, I think it makes often very good sense to keep variables in a model that are not statistically significant.  Here is a test I would use on whether to keep such variables in the model.  Rerun your model with just that one variable.  When you do so, is it now statistically significant and with a coherent directional sign that confirms the sign you have in your larger model.  If it is?  And, if that variable has much explanatory power whereby you now pretty much what sign it should have and it does in the models, I would consider keeping it and being rather liberal on the P value stuff.  Keep in mind, all precise statistical significance criteria are really arbitrary by definition.  What is more important is that your model makes sense, that it performs well (Hold Out and cross validation), and that the regression coefficients throughout the mentioned testing are reasonably stable... or when they are not... that you can readily explain why they are not.

Comment: I understand r is the strength of the correlation between the explanatory and the response var. I am not clear about the role of "standardized regression coefficients (beta-weights)" in Regression. What is the range of values for the standardized regression coefficients, so that we can interpret if it is low or high.

Comment: Standardized regression coefficients are very useful.  In summary, the correlation between two variables tells you how closely they are related (positive or negative correlation).  The regression coefficient tells you by how much Y changes given a change in X.  The standardized regression coefficients measure the relative influence on the various Xs on Y.  This is because it translates all X variables scale on the same scale...  for a one standard deviation in X, by how much (measured in standard deviation) is Y going to change.  Thus, you can rank what are the most influential X variables.

Comment: Let's say we have three variables: var A --> B --> C.  As it is, A is not directly correlated with C. If we regress between A and C, we obtain a low standardized regression coefficient (beta). But with a regression between B and C,  beta may be higher, indicating a direct correlation, which may not be mediated by any other var in between. Kindly advise if this interpretation of beta is correct. Thanks

Comment: Also, Is the range of values of standardized regression coefficients between 0 and 1, and -1 and 0, similar to r (Pearson coefficient)?

Comment: No, it is not.  Look up the precise definition of Standardized Coefficient (not enough space to do this here).  And, you will clearly see that it is not a constrained measure.  It can be much outside of + or - 1.  Also, I don't think your logic between correlation and standardized coefficient is correct.  An X variable can have a low correlation with Y, but have a higher standardized coefficient vs. another X variable.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to better interpret beta..I thought that if the value of beta is high (B --> C), then there may be a direct relationship between two var. But if beta is low, then, there may be an indirect correlation between the two var (A -->C), mediated by var B.

Comment: What is the difference between standardized and unstandardized coefficients in the coefficients table of a Regression? Do we need to report unstandardized coefficients B or standardized coefficients Beta?

Comment: Vyas, I encourage you to read Wikipedia articles on linear regression, multiple regression, correlation, etc.  The nature of your questions suggest you would get the most out of it.  That is preferable to my explaining just 500 characters at a time the foundation of regression.  Reporting both regular regression coefficients and standardized one is very useful information.  Also, just to let you know, your actual feedback is not appreciative.  You don't up vote my answer even though you voted it best.  You also don't upvote any of my comments.  You come across as you really don't care.

Comment: Vyas, my last comment was not supposed to be harsh.  I trust that from your side there is no ill-intent; and that you are truly appreciative of answers that resolve your many conundrums.  However, you are unfamiliar with how those open source platform work.  Nevertheless, I see that you have not yet acted on my not so subtle nudging.  I encourage you to do so.  You just will get more and better answers to your questions if you show signs of life on the appreciative side.

Comment: Hi Sympa, As a learner, I appreciate both positive and negative feedback with an open mind. Don't you worry, I was not clear about the difference of the standardized and unstandardized coefficients and how they are interpreted in Regression Analyses. I will listen to your kind advice - to check out wikipedia articles on Regression. I have tried to understand it from Laerd Statistics, but they are still not crystal clear to me. Thanks